# Show math macros and result in a table

Tags: verbatim, tcblisting

I'm writing some documentation about some macros I've made up. (I know there will probably be comments about the macros too, but that's not what I'm asking about.) Ideally, I'd like to make a sort of table where each row lists the macro itself, the result, and a comment.  Here is a MWE that shows what I'm currently doing and what I'd like to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\DeclareTCBListing{macrobox}{s G{} }{IfBooleanTF={#1}{}{listing side text},title=#2,
  listing options={style=tcblatex,commentstyle=\color{red!70!black}}
}

% Funny macro - don't worry about this part
\NewDocumentCommand{\TnidxRoot}{m m m m m m m}{%
  {#1}_{1} #2 %
  \IfBooleanF{#5}{{#1}_{2} #2} % 
  \IfBooleanTF{#6}{ % 
    {#1}_{3} % 3D
    \IfBooleanT{#7}{#2 {#1}_{4} } % 4D
  }{ % 
    \IfBooleanTF{#3}{\cdots}{\dots} #2 {#1}_{#4} %
  }%
}
% Funny macro - don't worry about this part
\NewDocumentCommand{\Tnsz}{s s t! G{n} O{d}}{%
  \TnidxRoot{#4}{\times}{\BooleanTrue}{#5}{#3}{#1}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

What I currently do is this:
\begin{macrobox}{Size commands}
$\Tnsz$          \\ % Default
$\Tnsz!$         \\ % Compact, no 2nd index
$\Tnsz{m}$        % Change main letter
\end{macrobox}


But I'd like a nice macro to generate rows of the following table, where the macro for row 1 might be something like \verb|\ExampleRow{\Tnsz}{Default}|.

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  \LaTeX\ Command & Result & Description \\ \hline
  \verb|\Tnsz| & $\Tnsz$ & Default \\ \hline
  \verb|\Tnsz!| & $\Tnsz!$ & Compact, no second index \\ \hline
  \verb|\Tnsz{m}| & $\Tnsz{m}$ & Change main letter \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not so different from Ulrich's proposal, but with a simpler coding. The macro has a *-variant for material to be printed in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment if using LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\ExampleRow}{svm}
 {
  \texttt{#2} &
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{$} \tl_rescan:nn { } { #2 } \IfBooleanT{#1}{$} &
  #3 \\
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
\ExampleRow{\fbox{a}}{Make a framed box}
\ExampleRow{\framebox[2cm][l]{a}}{Make a framed box}
\ExampleRow*{\sin}{Sine function}
\ExampleRow*{\xrightarrow{f}}{Extendable arrow}
\ExampleRow*{\xrightarrow[g]{}}{Extendable arrow}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first argument is absorbed verbatim, but then it is rescanned in order to be used for the second column, possibly in between `$` characters.

Comment: Thanks, @egreg. This works too! I've accepted it as the solution because it is indeed simpler. I am curious if you have a suggested reference to learn more about the ExplSyntax and tl_rescan functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

*I have edited my example and—following egreg's example—added an asterisk argument:*
*With `\ExampleRow*{...` the code is executed in math mode.*
*With `\ExampleRow{...` the code is only executed in math mode if the code itself contains directives for switching to math mode.*

*Unlike egreg, however, I do not use `\tl_rescan:nn`, but still use `\scantokens`, because when using `\scantokens`, things like `\verb|...|`, which switch to verbatim mode, also work. With `\tl_rescan:nn` such things do not work.*

*The subtle but crucial differences between `\scantokens` and `\tl_rescan:nn` are dealt with in the questions

[What is the essential/crucial difference between \scantokens/\tex_scantokens:D and \tl_rescan:nn?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/571304)

and

[expl3 - how can you pass the content of a token-list-variable as argument to another "function"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/571151/118714)*

---

As xparse is in use, you can probably have `\ExampleRow`

- read an argument of type v (verbatim),
- print it with `\verbatim@font` in effect for showing the coding
- feed it to `\scantokens`, nested in `$` and trailed by `%` (`\scantokens` does insert `\endlinechar`...) for showing the result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\DeclareTCBListing{macrobox}{s G{} }{IfBooleanTF={#1}{}{listing side text},title=#2,
  listing options={style=tcblatex,commentstyle=\color{red!70!black}}
}

% Funny macro - don't worry about this part
\NewDocumentCommand{\TnidxRoot}{m m m m m m m}{%
  {#1}_{1} #2 %
  \IfBooleanF{#5}{{#1}_{2} #2} % 
  \IfBooleanTF{#6}{ % 
    {#1}_{3} % 3D
    \IfBooleanT{#7}{#2 {#1}_{4} } % 4D
  }{ % 
    \IfBooleanTF{#3}{\cdots}{\dots} #2 {#1}_{#4} %
  }%
}
% Funny macro - don't worry about this part
\NewDocumentCommand{\Tnsz}{s s t! G{n} O{d}}{%
  \TnidxRoot{#4}{\times}{\BooleanTrue}{#5}{#3}{#1}{#2}%
}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% This is what I would probably do:
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begingroup
\makeatletter
% Let's use ^^A instead of %.
% Make % other so it can be "fed" to \scantokens to handle \scantokens'
% insertion of \endlinechar;
\catcode`\^^A=14\relax
\catcode`\%=12\relax
\@firstofone{^^A
  \endgroup
  \NewDocumentCommand\ExampleRow{svm}{^^A
    {\verbatim@font#2}&^^A
    {\IfBooleanT{#1}{$}\scantokens{#2%}\IfBooleanT{#1}{$}}&^^A
    {#3}\\\hline^^A
  }^^A
}%
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

What I currently do is this:
\begin{macrobox}{Size commands}
$\Tnsz$          \\ % Default
$\Tnsz!$         \\ % Compact, no 2nd index
$\Tnsz{m}$        % Change main letter
\end{macrobox}


But I'd like a nice macro to generate rows of the following table, where the macro for row 1 might be something like \verb|\ExampleRow{\Tnsz}{Default}|.

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  \LaTeX\ Command & Result & Description \\ \hline
  \verb|\Tnsz| & $\Tnsz$ & Default \\ \hline
  \verb|\Tnsz!| & $\Tnsz!$ & Compact, no second index \\ \hline
  \verb|\Tnsz{m}| & $\Tnsz{m}$ & Change main letter \\ \hline
  \verb+\verb|verbatim stuff|+ & \verb|verbatim stuff| & verbatim material \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Here it is:

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  \LaTeX\ Command & Result & Description \\ \hline
  \ExampleRow*{\Tnsz}{Default}%
  \ExampleRow*{\Tnsz!}{Compact, no second index}%
  \ExampleRow*{\Tnsz{m}}{Change main letter}%
  \ExampleRow{\verb|verbatim stuff|}{verbatim material}%
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @UlrichDiez, for the solution! This is working well so far. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Ah! This is really interesting. Thank you for the tweak. I didn't realize the differences. I will check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like the following? (this time no extra spaces after macro names)

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\strings[1]{\@tfor\sss:=#1\do{\expandafter\string\sss}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\ExampleRow[2]{\texttt{\strings{#1}} & $#1$ & #2 \\}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\strings[1]{\@tfor\sss:=#1\do{\expandafter\string\sss}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\ExampleRow[2]{\texttt{\strings{#1}} & $#1$ & #2 \\}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
  \ExampleRow{\times!\times}{binary product}
  \ExampleRow{\prod}{generic product}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

**Old solution** (macro names will be followed by spaces)

Maybe something like

```
\newcommand\ExampleRow[2]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}} & $#1$ & #2 \\}
```

is sufficient for your purpose?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\ExampleRow[2]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}} & $#1$ & #2 \\}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
  \ExampleRow{\times}{binary product}
  \ExampleRow{\prod}{generic product}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @gernot! The main problem with detokenize that I can see if that it adds spaces, which are a problem for some of the commands I need to demo.

Comment: @tgkolda I've added another solution that does not introduce spaces.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've accepted your solution. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I had trouble with the following:
`\ExampleRow{x \text{ and } y}{Example math}`

Comment: @tgkolda Try Ulrich's solution, seems to handle all cases.