# Language question: with \x defined as <X>, why using command \x is not the same as using <X>

Tags: parsing, tokenization

This is intended more as a LaTeX language question than a "how do I accomplish XYZ" question.

In the code below, a usage of `VerbatimOut` is successful.
Place that usage inside a `\newcommand*` definition, and using the new command fails.

From the language perspective, why are these not equivalent?
What happens when tokenizing, processing, etc that causes these to have different behaviors?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newcommand*{\writeToFile}{
\begin{VerbatimOut}{myFileFromCommand.txt}
fromCommand
\end{VerbatimOut}
\input{myFileFromCommand.txt}
}

\begin{document}

% works
\begin{VerbatimOut}{myFileFromPlain.txt}
fromPlain
\end{VerbatimOut}
\input{myFileFromPlain.txt}

% fails with error "FancyVerb Error: Extraneous input ` fromCommand \end {VerbatimOut} \input{myFileFromCommand.txt} ' between \begin{VerbatimOut}[<key=value>] and line end.
\writeToFile

\end{document}
```

Note: (likely better on `meta` discussion, but I don't have enough rep to post there) I've seen that many questions of "why do I get error E when trying to X with code C?" get answered with:

- (A) You can't use C - here's D that works
- (B) Read the TeX book and the documentation for C

Upsides of these answers:

- (A) is great for one-time LaTeX programmers who don't care about learning and just want something that does X
- (B) is great for LaTeX experts who already know how TeX works - they just need to look at C

Downsides of these answers:

- (A) is only useful for people who have the exact same goal X, and usually X is fairly specific
- (B) is daunting for novices who want just enough information to understand the error and search for a solution

Perhaps some kind of debugging mode that shows the operations LaTeX ran (showing before and after expanding each user-defined command, and showing which token is currently being processed) would help, both for individual debugging and posting the "why" something went wrong/right.

Comment: Meta-answer: my opinion, ● that's already way better than only include the (A) part, ● it gets boring to copy stuff from the TeXbook over and over again, ● TeX is really **that** complicated, you'd better read the book anyway. ■ [tools - How to best debug LaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538/how-to-best-debug-latex) -- a debugger is not impossible, but would be a **huge** amount of work.

Comment: ... that having said I thought the requirement for posting on meta is 5 reputation? You have 45 so more than enough

Comment: and usually Ulrich Diez's answers (one particular author,  there's more) are of the "re-explain everything every time" kind. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/629173/250119 ■ https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/605751/250119 should contain what you want.

Comment: @user202729 my bad - I remember seeing I didn't have enough initially and misremembered it as 50. I'll post the meta discussion there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a general rule that verb-like commands that make catcode changes may not be used in the argument of another command.

To see why you get a runaway argument `VerbatimOut` changes the interpretation of `\`  so that it is a normal character and `\foo` instead of making the single token with name `foo` it makes 4 character tokens `\`  `f` `o` `o`

So `\end{VerbatimOut}` would not be interpreted as `\end` with argument `VerbatimOut`  in order to stop processing the environment checks for the string and ends the environment by hand.

But your definition is saved with normal catcodes in force

```
\newcommand*{\writeToFile}{
\begin{VerbatimOut}{myFileFromCommand.txt}
fromCommand
\end{VerbatimOut}
\input{myFileFromCommand.txt}
}
```

has an `\end` token  a open group `{` token and character tokens `VerbatimOut`  so the expected verbatim character tokens `\end{VerbatimOut}` are never found.

Comment: So `\begin{VerbatimOut}` is waiting to finish, looking for the sequence of 17 tokens: `\ ` `e` `n` `d` `{` `V` `e` `r` `b` `a` `t` `i` `m` `O` `u` `t` `}` but it actually sees 14 tokens: `\end` `{` `V` `e` `r` `b` `a` `t` `i` `m` `O` `u` `t` `}`?

(And in addition to the first token not matching, the `{` wouldn't match `{` because they have different catcodes?)

Comment: Is there a "safety" setting that users can enable to catch mistakes like this with a meaningful error message, when a verb command is used somewhere it can't be?

A similar question applies to invalid usage of "fragile" commands in general.

Comment: @DavidFink yes to your first comment, no to your second

Comment: @DavidFink Yes, to a limited extent. xparse's v-type argument kind of implement that, at the cost of (probably much, I didn't benchmark) slower parsing.